# How to write in an alignment in latex

Tags: equations, alignment

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{documennt}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]

\item 

$x^{p^{r}q^{s}}+1$

\vspace{0.3cm} 
=$(x^{p^{r}})^{q^{s}}+1$

\vspace{0.3cm} 
=$(1+x^{p^r})(1+x^{p^r}+x^{2p^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)p^r})(1+x^{qp^r}+x^{2qp^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)qp^r})\cdots(1+x^{q^{s-1}p^r}+x^{2q^{s-1}p^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)p^{s-1}p^r})$

\vspace{0.3cm} 
=$(1+x)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1})(1+x^p+x^{2p}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p})\\(1+x^{p^2}+x^{2p^2}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p^2})\cdots(1+x^{p^{r-1}}+x^{2p^{r-1}}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p^{r-1}}) \\(1+x^{p^r}+x^{2p^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)p^r})(1+x^{qp^r}+x^{2qp^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)qp^r})\cdots(1+x^{q^{s-1}p^r}+x^{2q^{s-1}p^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)p^{s-1}p^r}) .$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to write these equation in LaTeX in alignment, but it is not coming. How I can do that. Please give some idea.

Comment: Could you please post a full compilable code, not just a snippet?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do here? (1) why are you using a list? (2) why inline math? (aka `$...$`) Why arent you using something like the `align*` environment, which to be explained in any decent introduction to latex.

Comment: Do you use an `enumerate` environment only to have  equation numbers on the left?

Comment: when I tried allign, the equation does not fit in the page, it comes out and it looks bad. How I can improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]
(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\[\medmath{
\begin{aligned}
x^{p^{r}q^{s}}+1
    & = \bigl(x^{p^{r}}\bigr)^{q^{s}}+1                   \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \bigl(1+x^{p^r}\bigr)
            \bigl(1+x^{p^r}+x^{2p^r} + \cdots + x^{(q-1)p^r}\bigr)         \\
            \bigl(1+x^{qp^r}+x^{2qp^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)qp^r}\bigr)\cdots    \\
            \bigl(1+x^{q^{s-1}p^r}+x^{2q^{s-1}p^r}+\cdots + x^{(q-1)p^{s-1}p^r}\bigr)
        \end{multlined}\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \bigl(1+x\bigr)\bigl((1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}\bigr)
             \bigl(1+x^p+x^{2p}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p}\bigr)   \\
        \bigl(1+x^{p^2}+x^{2p^2}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p^2}\bigr)\cdots
             \bigl(1+x^{p^{r-1}}+x^{2p^{r-1}}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p^{r-1}}\bigr) \\
        \bigl(1+x^{p^r}+x^{2p^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)p^r}\bigr)
             \bigl(1+x^{qp^r}+x^{2qp^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)qp^r}\bigr)\cdots\\
             \bigl(1+x^{q^{s-1}p^r} + x^{2q^{s-1}p^r} + \cdots + x^{(q-1)p^{s-1}p^r}\bigr).
        \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
}
\]
\end{document}
```

In above MWE are used `aligned` from `amsmath` (loaded by `mathtools` package) for aligning equations at equal sign and `multlined` from `mathtools` package for split long equation into more lines. With `\medmath{ ... }` from `nccmath` is used for reducing equation size.

The purpose of `itemize` is not clear. Do you like to have numbered equation on the left side? Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools, nccmath}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\medmath{
\begin{aligned}%[t]
x^{p^{r}q^{s}}+1
    & = \bigl(x^{p^{r}}\bigr)^{q^{s}}+1                   \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \bigl(1+x^{p^r}\big)
            \bigl(1+x^{p^r}+x^{2p^r} + \cdots + x^{(q-1)p^r}\big)         \\
            \bigl(1+x^{qp^r}+x^{2qp^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)qp^r}\big)\cdots    \\
            \bigl(1+x^{q^{s-1}p^r}+x^{2q^{s-1}p^r}+\cdots +x^{(q-1)p^{s-1}p^r}\big)
        \end{multlined}\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        \bigl(1+x\big)\bigl(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{p-1}\big)
             \bigl(1+x^p+x^{2p}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p}\big)   \\
        \bigl(1+x^{p^2}+x^{2p^2}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p^2}\big)\cdots \\
             \bigl(1+x^{p^{r-1}}+x^{2p^{r-1}}+\cdots+x^{(p-1)p^{r-1}}\big) \\
        \bigl(1+x^{p^r}+x^{2p^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)p^r}\big)\\
             \bigl(1+x^{qp^r}+x^{2qp^r}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)qp^r}\big)\cdots\\
             \bigl(1+x^{q^{s-1}p^r} + x^{2q^{s-1}p^r} + \cdots + x^{(q-1)p^{s-1}p^r}\big).
        \end{multlined}
\end{aligned}
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Its a very nice answer.